# #ifdef not working as expected with precompiled headers

Tags: c++, macros

I have part of code like below:

```
#define FEATURE_A 1

void function()
{
// some code

#ifdef FEATURE_A
    // code to be executed when this feature is defined
#endif

// some code

}
```

The program does not execute code inside **#ifdef** - **#endif**. But when I change **#ifdef** to **#ifndef** and remove **#define** macro, the code get executed. The code below work as expected.

```
//#define FEATURE_A 1

void function()
{
// some code

#ifndef FEATURE_A
    // code to be executed when this feature is defined
#endif

// some code

}
```

Can anyone explain why in the first case code inside **#ifdef** - **#endif** not executed and in second case it work? Can anyone tell me what setting might be wrong?

Not sure if this matter, I'm using visual studio 2010.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :**
When I clean and re-run, the second one also not working. its only show in editor as code that enabled.

When I define macro in project->property->Configuration Properties-> c/c++ -> Preprocessor , both of them working fine.

Comment: are you sure that you do not have `#undef FEATURE_A` somewhere?

Comment: If you want to see the code after the preprocessing do compile with the `-E` flag

Comment: You need to post a whole program that exhibits this behavior, since it otherwise doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have check it just now.

Comment: I remember I had many problems with Visual Studio and what sometimes helped is clearing the object files it keeps for the project. Try it - maybe it will help

Comment: try to create minimal reproducible example and post code here

Comment: I am not sure if this is related, my project have lots of optimization setting, is it possible that problem arise due to this?

Comment: Please post your original code. What is the actual name of your macro and the actual name of your function, etc?  I assume your code does not use the words `function` and `FEATURE_A`. You may have a name clash with some existing macro in the system headers. It is also possible that you misspelled something and you just don't see it.

Comment: @MarkLakata : I have try change macro name many time. so i am sure, there is no name conflict

Comment: A common error, is to "définie" the same thing in several header file, have you perform an exhaustive search of FEATURE_A across the solution ?

Comment: I even try name that not make any sense like ALPHAGAMMA.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is likely because of how Microsoft implements precompiled headers. You actually have

```
#define FEATURE_A 1
#include "stdafx.h" // <- all code even ascii art before that line is ignored.

void function()
{
// some code

#ifdef FEATURE_A
    // code to be executed when this feature is defined
#endif

// some code

}
```

Move it after precompiled header and all works:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // <- all code even ascii art before that line is ignored.
#define FEATURE_A 1

void function()
{
// some code

#ifdef FEATURE_A
    // code to be executed when this feature is defined
#endif

// some code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have multiple `Platform`, so I need to define `Preprocessor` for each `Platform`.

[image]